# Open new window when clicking Unity launcher icons?

Tags: unity, launcher

**Background**

[I realize middle-clicking on a Launcher icon opens a new instance](https://askubuntu.com/a/28087/560991), but my mouse doesn't have a good middle-click option (clicking the scrollwheel works for this, but it's cumbersome). My workflow tends to involve numerous windows for programs such as terminal and Chrome. Currently, terminal opens new windows when I click the Launcher icon, but Chrome and Nautilus do not.

**Research**

I found out how to list all the keys associated with `org.compiz.unityshell` by way of an article on [OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/10-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-lts), and got this list:

```
user@comp> gsettings list-keys org.compiz.unityshell
override-decoration-theme
disable-show-desktop
launcher-switcher-forward
reveal-trigger
reveal-pressure
alt-tab-prev-window
launcher-capture-mouse
stop-velocity
panel-opacity-maximized-toggle
automaximize-value
spread-app-windows
panel-first-menu
decay-rate
alt-tab-bias-viewport
background-color
lock-screen
backlight-mode
dash-blur-experimental
edge-responsiveness
show-minimized-windows
inactive-shadow-color
low-graphics-mode
spread-app-windows-anywhere
alt-tab-timeout
switch-strictly-between-applications
autohide-animation
shadow-y-offset
inactive-shadow-radius
menus-discovery-duration
launcher-switcher-prev
menus-fadeout
shadow-x-offset
icon-size
overcome-pressure
dash-tap-duration
execute-command
alt-tab-forward
show-launcher
edge-passed-disabled-ms
launcher-opacity
show-desktop-key
show-hud
scroll-inactive-icons
disable-mouse
alt-tab-next-window
num-launchers
menus-fadein
panel-opacity
launcher-hide-mode
active-shadow-radius
menus-discovery-fadeout
keyboard-focus
alt-tab-prev
urgent-animation
active-shadow-color
launcher-minimize-window
alt-tab-prev-all
launch-animation
menus-discovery-fadein
show-menu-bar
alt-tab-forward-all
shortcut-overlay
user@comp>
```

However, none of these look very promising. I have also found other questions wanting to [do exactly the opposite of what I want to do](https://askubuntu.com/q/125730/560991), but I couldn't determine from those questions how to reverse it.

**Question**

Is there a way to make the Unity Launcher open new windows for all programs when left-clicking and not just when middle-clicking?

Comment: There is an easy way to enable "middle button emulation" so that right+left click will be a middle click. This would be the next easiest solution to the physical middle button on mouse. But I guess you have tried this.

Comment: @clearkimura that's actually a good idea that i hadn't considered. I'm going to check Unity Tweak Tool and CompizConfig Settings Manager to see if either can set up a custom click option for just the Unity Launcher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what you want:

The easiest thing to do is:

1. Remove your existing Chrome icon from the Unity launcher
2. Open the Unity Dash and make it non-maximized

Then:

1. Type "chrome"
2. Drag the Chrome icon to your desktop
3. Right-click on the Chrome icon on your desktop and choose "Properties"
4. Modify "Command" to insert `&` at the end and close the window
5. Drag the icon from the desktop to your Unity launcher

You can use any folder instead of `desktop` if you have problem with it.

Comment: Perfect! Sorry I was late to check my bounty; it was auto-awarded to @Hamed. But your solution is the appropriate answer for what I want.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope it would help

Comment: @JonathanLandrum About bounty, sorry about making trouble. Would it help if I delete my answer?
If yes, please let me know, else I would leave my answer hence it might be useful for someone.

Comment: @Hamed not at all, your solution likely works for someone. Leave it as it is. And besides, I offered the bounty because I needed help, and you helped. :o)

Answer (score 6):

For opening a new window instead of `middle click` you can use <kbd>shift</kbd> + `left click` on a launcher icon.

For nautilus it won't work if your current folder is home. While you may rarely use two nautilus windows for the same -home- folder, it will not be a problem.

Comment: woah this is super neat...